# Find value between two array values

Tags: java, arrays, bisection

I want my function to take a value x and find the in between values of my array shown below:

```
double[] xlist = {51.8, 10.3, 5.1, 2.6, 1.7, 1.29, 1.03, 0.86, 0.65, 0.52, 0.43, 0.37, 0.32, 0.29};
```

- Example 1: When x = 1.5, The high value equals 1.7 and the low value equals 1.29
- Example 2: When x = 12, The high value equals 51.8 and the low value equals 10.3

I am using a derivative of the bisection method to find these "high" and "low" values but there is something wrong with my code. My code is shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] xlist = {51.8, 10.3, 5.1, 2.6, 1.7, 1.29, 1.03, 0.86, 0.65, 0.52, 0.43, 0.37, 0.32, 0.29};
    double x = 0.9; //or whatever declare x to equal
    int high = xlist.length;
    int mid = 0, low = 0;
    while (low != high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
                if (xlist[mid] > x) {
                    low = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    high = mid;
                }
            }
    System.out.println(xlist[mid - 1] + "\n" + x + "\n" + xlist[mid]);
  }
```

My console output is shown below:

```
51.8
12.0
10.3
```

It works but when I change the x value to say 9.9 I get:

```
5.1
9.9
2.6
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not using an easier method ? Would you mind to do it differently ?

Comment: It looks like you should be using xlist[high] + "\n" + x + "\n" + xlist[low] where high would be the index of the high value and low is the index of the low value

Comment: I'm sure there is an easier method to use to find these values but I don't know how to write it. If you have an alternative to what I'm using currently, It would be very helpful.

Comment: @Cary By the end of the while loop xlist[high] and xlist[low] will be equal to each other.

Comment: Consider looking for x=1.5.  You can get down to `low=4` & `high=5` (values 1.7 and 1.29, respectively).  This will compute `mid=4`, and `x` will be smaller than `1.7`, so `low = mid + 1` is executed and `low` becomes `5`.  But at this point, `mid` is still equal to `4`, so you print out `mid-1` and `mid` values ... which are `xlist[3]` and `xlist[4]` giving `2.6` and `1.7`!

Comment: The answer you have (currently) accepted is **wrong**.  Using `double` for `low` and `high` indices is bad (indices should be `int`), but worse is looping `while (low != high) {...}`.  This is comparing `double` values for equality.  When using bisection to find the bracketing values, with 14 elements in the array, bisection should take ceil(log2(14))==4 loop iterations.  The answer you accepted takes **56 iterations** in my test looking for the values bracketing 1.5.  A bisection approach taking 56 iterations would be necessary only for an array 2^56 = 72 quadrillion entries long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are dividing `(low + high)/2` you are assigning the result into and int value and are losing some data.  What I have done below is change the data type of high, mid, and low to "double"  and then cast the values to an int when referencing elements in your double array. Please try the code below.

```
        double[] xlist = {51.8, 10.3, 5.1, 2.6, 1.7, 1.29, 1.03, 0.86, 0.65, 0.52, 0.43, 0.37, 0.32, 0.29};
        double x = 9.9; //or whatever declare x to equal
        double high = xlist.length;
        double mid = 0.0, low = 0.0;
        while (low != high) {
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
                    if (xlist[(int)mid] > x) {
                        low = mid + 1;
                    } else {
                        high = mid;
                    }
                }
        System.out.println(xlist[(int)mid - 1] + "\n" + x + "\n" + 
xlist[(int)mid]);
```

Comment: No.  This is exactly what the problem was not.  Array indices should be `int`, not `double`.

Comment: @Preston White, Just be aware that the same truncation occurs when you cast the double values to int values when referencing elements in your double[].  Please click the check mark next to this solution if it answers your question, thanks!

Comment: When using `double`, the test `while (low != high)` is comparing **floating point** numbers for **equality**, which is always a dangerous thing to do.  In this case, when searching for `1.5`, I find the `while` loop executes **56 times** before terminating!!!  Considering this array is only 14 elements long, any gain in using a bisection approach has been lost!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simpler approach:

- sort the array
- use [`Arrays.binarySearch(xlist, x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-double:A-double-) to find the position `p` where `x` could be inserted
- if `p >= 0`, `x` is at that position in the array
- if `p < 0`, `-p-1` is the position of the smallest element that is greater than `x` and `-p-2` is the position of the largest element that is less than `x`.

Make sure to add relevant checks (is `-p-2>=0` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because you are updating `mid`, testing, and then changing either the `low` or `high` index.  If the loop exits after updating `high = mid`, then `mid` value was equal to the `low` index and everything is fine `mid == low == high`.  If the loop exits after updating `low = mid + 1`, then `mid` was equal to the `low`, but now `mid == low-1 == high-1`.  This results in the off-by-one error which is sometimes seen.

The code also suffers from `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the search runs near the ends of the array.  This is due to accessing `xlist[mid-1]`, where `mid` can reach `0`.  The `high` index starts out one position beyond the end of the array, and if used as an index would also generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

A better solution would be to start `low` at `0` and `high` at `xlist.length-1`, and loop until the `low` and `high` limits are 1 index apart.  At that point, they are exactly the bounds you are looking for:

```
    int low = 0, high = xlist.length - 1;
    while (high - low > 1) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (xlist[mid] > x) {
            low = mid;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(xlist[low] + "\n" + x + "\n" + xlist[high]);
```